# How to display images of different dimensions in standardized divs

Tags: css, image

I have a number of images, which are of all different dimensions.  Some are taller than they are wide, and vice versa.  Each image is in a responsive div set to be the size of the viewport (thus all divs are the same size).  I would like any given image to show in its div with no cropping.  A portrait image would max out at the height of the viewport.  A landscape image would max out at the width of the viewport.  Any leftover width or height in the div would just be empty and the images would not be distorted.  Is this possible?

Comment: What language? Markup ..? But welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Oh, it's all in HTML and CSS.  I'd like to avoid Javascript for this.  Sorry!  And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```css
#frame {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:30px;

}

#img {
    margin:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
    <img src="http://pds15.egloos.com/pds/200906/18/49/f0063949_4a3910adbcd4b.jpg" alt="arctic fox" />
</div>


<img id="img" src="http://pds15.egloos.com/pds/200906/18/49/f0063949_4a3910adbcd4b.jpg" alt="arctic fox" />
```

If above is what you wanted, `overflow` property is what you're probably looking for.

You can set a `overflow : hidden` css property on the divs, then no matter how big or small your images are, it won't overflow the boxs as long as it stays inside of them.